# Log on to Bloomberg Anywhere automatically

Tags: vbscript, bloomberg

I've written a JAVA program that accesses some of the Bloomberg API.  The data gets stored as a file on my PC.  However, I would ideally like to set up a cron job that allows me to run my script every day at 5AM, before I get into the office.  I have a Bloomberg Anywhere account, are there any examples of VB scripts that will allow me to log in to the account on my machine automatically?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you don't have to have the Bloomberg terminal running in order to use the API. I don't think that this is the defined behavior, but as long as you haven't logged on to your Bloomberg account on a different PC or mobile device and haven't rebooted your PC - the API should work.

Comment: This is correct; however, I think it is intentional behaviour. My understanding is that Bloomberg has put this in for exactly the reasons Korra requires, i.e. so that you can schedule/run early morning reports before you get into the office/log in. I think it's at least 3 days so that you can run reports on Monday morning without having to log in to Bloomberg over the weekend.